# Kodi hangs on splash screen at first run; apparent database error in logfile

Tags: database, kodi

On a freshly installed 64bit Ubuntu 18.04 system with Intel graphics, a freshly installed `kodi` hangs at the splash screen.  The log file appears nominal until the last three lines.

```
2019-09-15 08:17:16.734 T:139670001514240  NOTICE: Running database version Addons27
2019-09-15 08:17:16.735 T:139670001514240   ERROR: SQL: [ViewModes6.db] SQLite error SQLITE_ERROR (no such table: version)
                                            Query: SELECT idVersion FROM version
2019-09-15 08:17:16.792 T:139670001514240   ERROR: Process error processing job
```

I tried `kodi` both from the stock repos and the stable ppa, both had the same problem.

I've installed `kodi` successfully on several systems and AFAIK didn't do anything different this time - what's causing it to hang here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Help I received at https://forum.kodi.tv/ led to the discovery that databases used by the application were corrupted.  I'm unsure *how* this happened since this is a fresh Kodi install on a fresh Ubuntu install... At any rate, I simply deleted all the files out of `/home/[user]/.kodi/userdata/Database/` and it started up fine on the next attempt.

Answer (score 1):

You could 'repair' the missing data
I dont remind where is stored the `ViewModes6.db` file, lets say its
`~/.kodi/userdata/Database/ViewModes6.db`
The concerned table contains only 1 line, if there is no other missing component it will be a quick fix .

```
# Install sqlite3 if not present
sudo apt-get install sqlite3

# Define db file location (setup your own)
DbFile="~/.kodi/userdata/Database/ViewModes6.db"

# Create the version table
sqlite3 $DbFile "CREATE TABLE version (idVersion integer, iCompressCount integer);"

# Fill in the table with default data (only 1 line!)
sqlite3 $DbFile "insert into version (idVersion, iCompressCount) values (6, 0);"
```

---

You can also use the `sqlitebrowser` GUI if you want it a bit easier

```
sudo apt install sqlitebrowser
```

[image]
[image]

Comment: Thanks! Since this was a fresh install, I just deleted all the files out of the database folder and then the program started. I got help at https://forum.kodi.tv